# video not playing on mobile > Wordpress Avada theme fusion slider

Tags: javascript, wordpress, mobile, html5-video

I have a video in my fusion slider but on mobile it changes the video into an image but I want to show video on mobile. After asking the support they say it's not possible because it's a background video in the slider and not a layer.

If I put the video element in my page it works so I removed on the fusion slider the image so I see the video but it won't play. The video element is exactly the same and if I inspect the element and edit the element with the option edit in HTML and just put an empty div after the video element and go out of the editor my video starts playing.

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay="autoplay" loop="loop" muted="" width="1800" height="700">
    <source src="http://domain.be/wp-content/uploads/2018/10/video.mp4" type="video/webm" />
</video>
```

I tried to refresh the element by getting the content in the innerHTML and save it back in the innerHTML but didn't work. Then I tried to add an event listener to the video element but no success.

```
var v = document.getElementsByTagName("video")[0];
v.addEventListener('canplay', function() {
    v.play();
});
```

My fusion slider:

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the fusion slider but video background works fine on mobile if you use the revolution slider.